# How to inject service which depends on script running before it?

Tags: angularjs

In my index.html I have the following code:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var sessionId = document.URL.substr(document.URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'login/' + sessionId + '?format=json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // if not logged in, then variable is not even defined.
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                        window.bootstrappedUserObject = response;
                    }

                });
            });
   </script>
```

As my services are loaded I have a service as follows:

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('helloApp.controllers');

app.factory('identity', function($window) {
    var currentUser;
    if (!!$window.bootstrappedUserObject) {
        currentUser = $window.bootstrappedUserObject;
    }
    return {
        currentUser: currentUser,
        isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
        isAdministrator: isAdministrator,
        sessionId : sessionId
    };

    function sessionId() {
        return currentUser.sessionId;
    }

    function isAdministrator() {
        return this.currentUser.IsAdmin;
    }

    function isAuthenticated() {
        return !!this.currentUser;
    }
});
})();
```

My service needs the previous script run before it is run otherwise $window.bootstrappedUserObject will always be undefined. How can I structure my calls so that the script has returned before I start building my service(s)?

Comment: where do you use the "identity" service at ?

Comment: In a directive for an element with template :             template: '<div id="overlay" ng-show="!identity.isAuthenticated()"><h1 class="centred" style="color:red">Not authenticated</h1></div>',

Comment: I think you should manually bootstrap your app instead of using `ng-app`.  Something like : `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])` when your `$.ajax` result has arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can also try using ng-if to only evaluate the directive only once $.ajax result has arrived

Example :

HTML

```
<div id="overlay" ng-show="!identity.isAuthenticated()" ng-if="Evaluate"><h1 class="centred" style="color:red">Not authenticated</h1></div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var sessionId = document.URL.substr(document.URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'login/' + sessionId + '?format=json',
                success: function (response) {
                    // if not logged in, then variable is not even defined.
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    window.bootstrappedUserObject = response;
                    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myApp]');
                    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.Evaluate = true;
                    });
                }

            });
        });
  </script>
```